# How can I install Minecraft?

Tags: java, software-installation, minecraft

I have tried many tutorials but none of them are clear enough. I have also tried installing it using Wine but it won't update and Wine goes gray and stops working.

Does anybody know an easy way to install Minecraft though the Java file without using Wine?

Comment: Please mark answer as answered if that solved your problem :).

Comment: Related: [How to correctly install and troubleshoot Minecraft (Client)](http://askubuntu.com/q/225432/176889)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not necessary to install Minecraft. All you need to do is [install Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java).

1. Now right click on your Minecraft.jar file and select "Open with Oracle Java 7 Runtime"

That's it. Enjoy!

Related:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)
- [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

Comment: It also works perfectly with OpenJDK. I actually find the sound works better with OpenJDK, at least on a 64bit system.

Answer (score 14):

Installation of Minecraft for 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04 is now possible with a PPA.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

---

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Easiest way. After installing via this method, just search the Unity Dash for "minecraft". Works for 13.10 too.

Comment: Does this also install Java?

Comment: I have confirmed that this answer also works in 14.10 with searching for "minecraft" in Unity Dash.  @rubo77 this does not also install Java, you can find that here though -- [How to install Java](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Answer (score 6):

Here's [a script](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1114574-enkouyamis-complete-ubuntu-installer-script/) to install minecraft and help troubleshoot most issues that can arise:

To get minecraft running, right click the minecraft.jar file, go to properties, permisions, and set it allow running as an executable. Now you can right click it, and run with a java.

If you want to properly have minecraft installed: have its icon, be able to launch with `minecraft` in terminal, show up on the applications menu, etc, follow these steps:

**1) Download minecraft to ~/.minecraft**

```
wget -P /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar
```

**2) Check which JavaVM is installed and which is set to default.**

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java -version
```

It is recommended to run minecraft with the latest stable java (7 aka 1.7) from Oracle, though running it with the open-source alternative OpenJDK works too.

If you have the one you want to use, OpenJDK 7 or Oracle Java 7, and it is NOT set as default, skip to step 4; if it is, skip to step 5.

**3) Installing Java**

To get Oracle Java 7, you need to first add a package repository repository that has it to download, refresh the package list, then download and install it, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update; sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
sudo apt-get install Oracle-java7-installer
```

To get OpenJDK 7, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-pluginter
```

**Next check again which is the default JavaVM using `java -version`**

**4) Change the default JavaVM**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

**5) Extract and rename the Minecraft icon**

```
unzip /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft/Minecraft.jar favicon.png -d /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft
mv /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft/favicon.png /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft/Minecraft.png
```

**6) Create a launcher in /usr/local/games/ so you can run minecraft with just `minecraft`.**

```
touch minecraft
echo "java -jar /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft/minecraft.jar" >> minecraft
```

**Moving and changing permission of Minecraft shell script**

```
sudo chmod +x minecraft
sudo mv minecraft /usr/local/games/
```

**7) Install the minecraft icon to your system**

```
xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor /home/$(whoami)/.minecraft/Minecraft.png
rm -rf Minecraft.png
```

**8) Create a desktop launcher (shortcut) for Minecraft**

```
touch 'Minecraft.desktop'
echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Version=1.0" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Name=Minecraft" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "GenericName=Game" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Comment=Minecraft is a game about placing blocks to build anything you can imagine." >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Exec=minecraft" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Terminal=false" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Icon=Minecraft"  >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Categories=Game;Application;" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Type=Application" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "StartupNotify=true" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Actions=RunInTerminal" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "[Desktop Action RunInTerminal]" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Name=Run in Terminal" >> Minecraft.desktop
echo "Exec=sudo gnome-terminal -x minecraft" >> Minecraft.desktop
```

**Granting the launcher executable permissions**

```
sudo chmod +x Minecraft.desktop
```

**Adding the shortcut to your application menu and adding it to your desktop**

```
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor Minecraft.desktop
xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate
mv Minecraft.desktop /home/$(whoami)/Desktop
```

Answer (score 5):

And to start minecraft use command `java -jar /path/to/Minecraft.jar`. If you want you can create desktop launcher for it so you dont need to start it from terminal every time.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible the problem is with some of the libraries he's using that he's using.  But the bug should be fixed in a later version of the libraries.  http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=57426 has a solution.  In short:

Procedure:

1. Make sure minecraft alpha has been run at least once so it can download the gamedata.
2. Download the latest version of the game engine: http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.5/lwjgl-2.5.zip/download
3. Open zip file in Archive Manager and open jar/ directory
4. Navigate to the minecraft game data directory in nautilus: /home/user/.minecraft/bin
5. Drag jinput.jar lwjgl.jar lwjgl_util.jar from the archive to the minecraft gamedata directory
6. Open native/linux/ in the archive
7. navigate to /home/user/.minecraft/bin/natives
8. Drag everything from native/linux/ to /home/user/.minecraft/bin/natives
9. Your done! Start the game!

Comment: Nice addition :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to have a java runtime installed (OpenJDK,sun-java), and execute the minecraft.jar with

```
java -jar /path/of/minecraft.jar
```

alternatively, you can right click the jar file and select to run it with your installed Java runtime.

You can even create an empty file and input the

```
java -jar /path/of/minecraft.jar
```

and you have created a shortcut!
On it's first run, or any time you force an update, minecraft will download all of the necessary files to /home/[user]/.minecraft. The game also stores you saves, stats, screenshots, etc. here. For consistency, I would recommend moving the minecraft.jar you would have downloaded into the .minecraft directory after you update the game.

May you mine many diamonds.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure that JDK6 is installed from the software centre.
2. Right click on the `minecraft.jar` and hit "Properties". Go to permissions, and allow it to be run as a program.
3. Open `minecraft.jar` with JDK6 (right click and choose "open with").

Answer (score 0):

If you create a launcher you can use the minecraft.png file from inside the jar as an icon. Just open it with your favorite zip manager (jars are zip files) and drag minecraft.png out.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this command:

`java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp Minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`

If that doesn't work go to http://www.minecraft.net/download.

Answer (score 0):

Install Java quickly:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

This will download the JRE/OpenJDK. Right click the Minecraft JAR file (the launcher, not the binary), and select "Open with OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Minecraft, I would suggest opening the ubuntu Software Centre (Ubuntu 9.04 & +) and search "Java" and install "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" after that install the latest launcher at >http://minecraft.net/download< and get the latest Minecraft launcher for your operating system. After that open your "Downloads Folder" or where ever you downloaded it and left click on the file and click properties, Got to the side where it says Permissions and click it. After that Look right down to the bottom of that windows and tick the box "Allow executing file as a program". Then at the top right of that window and click Open With after that select the Java JDK we downloaded and highlight it and press "Set as default". After that close the windows and double click to open the launcher you downloaded. There you go you have succsesfully installed the Minecraft Launcher on your tablet/computer! Enjoy P.S remember to always listen too me! :P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have marked Minecraft.jar as being allowed to run as an executable.  Right click Minecraft.jar. Click properties. Go to permissions tab. Check "Allow executing file as program".