# How do I Install Minecraft?

Tags: 10.04, installation, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-to-install-minecraft)

I've been searching everything that could possibly help, but nothing has worked, and I'm really getting annoyed, because Minecraft lags like no tomorrow on Windows. Can anyone please help me install Minecraft on Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have Sun JAVA installed.  Installing the JDK or the JRE is a sufficient way of doing this.  The JDK might be best.  Read here on how to install it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk

Then, from the Minecraft site, you will need to download the beta .jar file.  Download it to your Desktop.

Then, in terminal, do the following:

```
cd /home/username/Desktop
chmod +x minecraft.jar
```

Replace `username` with your username that you login to your computer with.

Then right click the Minecraft.jar file, and go into Properties.  Under the "Open With" tab, choose the option button that says "Sun Java Runtime" or similar wording.  Hit the "Close" button.

Finally, double-click the minecraft.jar file.  It should now run the Minecraft client.

Comment: Note that these are the steps I did on 11.04, and they are exactly the same for 10.04.