# How to start Minecraft

Tags: openjdk, minecraft

Before starting I want to state that the following 2 links are already done:

[How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

[How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I have the .minecraft folder in my user folder (/home/cyrex/.minecraft). The minecraft.jar file has the executable flag. The minecraft version is the 1.2.5. I have OpenJRE AND OpenJDK installed with version 1.6 and 1.7 (1.6 default). Already installed the liblwjgl-java library.

Still the game when I run it via terminal or via the Open With option with OpenJDK 1.6 throws me the following error (In terminal):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft. Program will exit.
```

When I start the game with:

`java -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame` or with

`java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp minecraft.jar net.minecraft.LauncherFrame`

(Notice in both cases the M from minecraft is lower case) it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/LauncherFrame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.LauncherFrame
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: net.minecraft.LauncherFrame. Program will exit.
```

Does not load and only throws that. What could it be?