# A possible Java problem causing a java program to not work?

Tags: 12.04, wine, java, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

I think I installed Java correctly from Oracle, but I'm not too sure. But I'm fairly confident, since when I use `java -version` I get this:

[image]

So, I'm running MineCraft with WINE. I didn't know how else to launch it and OpenSDK didn't do the trick either. Surprisingly, the start screen actually works and is functional. So, it's all cool. But when running the game, as expected, I get this:

[image]

Nothing. Black. Absolutely nothing.

So, my skilled peers - can you help me?!

In case you're wondering, when running, it comes up in the Unity dock-thing. I'm also running Precise 12.04. Also, it's in .jar format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Wine to run Minecraft - it's a Java program, which means it's supposed to be platform-independent. Wine is a compatibility layer for Windows programs .. which means you're trying to run a Java program using a Linux Java runtime inside a compatibility layer for Windows.

Unless you installed Java inside Wine, nothing will happen... and it's going to run better in the native Linux Java runtime anyway.

This question appears to cover it.

[How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)