# Please help newbie install jar

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

I am Kyler, and I have a 12.04LTS. Will you please help me with the installation of  minecraft

http://www.minecraft.net/

Comment: Hi Kyler, this question has already been discussed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft

Answer (score 1):

you need install open-jdk (java) in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre # to be able to run
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk # to be able to compile
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin # to be able to run applets on browser
```

source [blog xubuntugeek](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com.ar/2012/05/install-openjdk-7-in-xubuntu-1204.html)