# Minecraft High CPU (125%~) using openJava 6/7

Tags: 12.04, java, performance, minecraft

if I run Minecraft with OpenJDK 6 or 7 on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, it eats nearly of the CPU and I have lags during minecraft gameplay.

What I have tried so far:

- start minecraft with something like `java -Xmx2044M -Xms1024M  -jar minecraft.jar`
- Using recommended Nvdia drivers
- Using latest beta nvidia drivers
- Tested minecraft with both openJava Versions (6/7)
- Switched between Unity 2D and Unity 3D
- Verified that I am using the latest graphic engine that is used by Minecraft (LWJGL)

My machine is an AMD Phenom 955x using Ubuntu 12.04 with a Nvidia GTX 275

Until now nothing changed the bad performance of minecraft. Suggestions are much appreciated, thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/20906/7035 that is what saved me from that problem. Specially the part about the libraries. Not so much about the parameters needed for the java command.

Comment: Yes I tryed that already - That is meant by "Verified that I am using the latest graphic engine that is used by Minecraft (LWJGL)" What that guy is talking about exactly the procedure to update the LWJGL to the latest version. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [OptiFine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-145-optifine-hd-d3-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more/) - it's worked well for me in the past.

The [SSP mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/534818-132-olddaysnbxlite-ssp/) also works very well; Minecraft singleplayer now runs as a shell of SMP (thus enabling LAN connection), and this mod allows Minecraft to run like it used to, just as pure SSP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but did not help much - CPU Usage dropped from 125% to ~110% after i haved turned off most of the effects. I think it is not a graphic related problem

Comment: @Grrbrr404 Have you tried using Sun/Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK?

Comment: No I have not, because it seems no one else could solve it by installing Oracle Java - I have not found any confirmation on the web. And last but not least openJDK ist officially recommended by oracle for linux systems - Thats the reason why I would like to stick with openJDK. Thanks anyway