# How do I install MineCraft on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, games, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

I just recently dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on my gaming desktop. I have not installed Java yet as I have tried and failed miserably. 
So can you help? Please? I just want to play some MineCraft.

Comment: Have you tried the steps in the following [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)? Hope this helps.