# Minecraft Black Screen Ubunutu 12.10 using Java 7

Tags: java, minecraft

I get these errors when trying to run minecraft.

```
ian@ian-Beast:~$ cd ~/.minecraft
ian@ian-Beast:~/.minecraft$ cd /.bin
bash: cd: /.bin: No such file or directory
ian@ian-Beast:~/.minecraft$ cd ./bin
ian@ian-Beast:~/.minecraft/bin$ java -jar minecraft.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Any clues on how to fix?

Comment: 64bit or 32bit Ubuntu as it seems the 3D driver libraries are crashing

Answer (score 2):

Just realized...you are running minecraft directly, you don't run minecraft from the bin directory, you run it from the launcher.

Launcher is located on the minecraft.net site

https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft.jar

Same name, different programs

If that doesn't help refer to the following...

Definitive guide, I have been running Minecraft for a long time now and this guide has shown me a few tricks

[How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

Install Java 6 runtime and run minecraft.jar using it. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

For Minecraft on Linux, I've often found that you have to manually delete and reinstall the lwjgl libraries. This would make sense, because the errors you're getting are referencing lwjgl. Here's a [link](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/LWJGL) on how to do that.