# How do I install java? Want to play minecraft

Tags: downloads

complete novice at Ubuntu. Trying to set up minecraft to play through Ubuntu but saying I need to install plug ins to see them and my minecraft won't play as it's a jar file instead of a exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java) for how to install Java.

> 1. Now right click on your Minecraft.jar file and select "Open with Oracle Java 7 Runtime"
>
> That's it. Enjoy!
>
> Related:
>
> - [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)
> - [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

*<sub>Borrowed from https://askubuntu.com/a/5565/178596 — which could also be a possible duplicate.</sub>*