# Cannot download Minecraft

Tags: firefox, java, minecraft

Alright, now before I start I'm not the most tech savvy person out there so I dont know alot of terms and how to do things. I mean I know what a command, terminal, and argument is and all that but I can't understand everything so if you happen to answer my question, you have to help me through step by step. Anyway my question is, I am downloading Minecraft on ubuntu running the version 12.o1 and I go into firefox and go to the right page for it but I start the download and it asks what I want to do to the file. The only thing I can select  is save file. The minute I click download file, firefox crashes. I don't know why but I am selecting the right .jar file and everything. Then in my download folder I have a .jar minecraft file and I can't open it. The thing says you need to be able to execute it. So I go into properties and select the option. I can't seem to figure it out. Please help...

Comment: Try `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar`, and then `java -jar Minecraft.jar`

Comment: Also, have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft