# Start the minecraft.jar demo

Tags: minecraft

I [installed minecraft via PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/280685/34298):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

And now I can start the login screen for the game on the console with

```
java -jar /usr/share/minecraft/minecraft.jar
```

and even copy the running game-screen with

```
cp -a ~/.minecraft/ ~/mcraft
```

which allows me to start it without internet connection:

```
java -jar ~/mcraft/launcher.jar
```

Now since I don't have an account, how can I start the demo?

Comment: Ahh, you need an account for the demo: https://minecraft.net/demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as it is:

- You have to create an account at https://minecraft.net/demo (You can use any fantasy email as it doesn't have to be valid for the demo to run once.)
- Log in in your game-screen and press the DEMO Button

The game will download the rest it needs to run.