# Minecraft Launcher getting stuck at "Starting Launcher" in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, launcher, minecraft

I [installed minecraft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft) the way I was supposed to.

When I boot up the launcher this is what I get:

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Dec 6, 2015 9:52:08 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.2.0-19-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_91'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Looking for update
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Got reply in: 800ms
No update found.
Unpacking /home/seph/.minecraft/launcher.pack to /home/seph/.minecraft/launcher.jar
Cleaning up /home/seph/.minecraft/launcher.pack
Starting launcher.
```

And then it just hangs here, and tends to stop responding after about 30 seconds.  Has anyone seen this before, or does anyone know how I can figure out more about what's going wrong?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What version of Java or JDK are you using, and where did you install it from? I can see 1.7, but what JDK?

Comment: I edited my question to have "$java -version" in it

Comment: though it says "System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'" up above

Comment: @DavidCole

Thank you, you got me right on track.

Comment: I noticed this after an upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. It seems that the launcher will also apparently randomly work like 1/40 of the time, for some reason. However, OpenJDK always has worked for Minecraft in the past, and I'd like to keep using it if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the wrong JRE, even though it looked like I had the right one.

Installing the Oracle JDK fixed the problem:

See how to here: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after installing OpenJDK 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

No need for installing the Orakle JDK.

(Currently using 15.10 64bit)