# Java isn't working

Tags: java, minecraft

I installed Java 7 and 8 using ppa:webupd8 and my terminal says it is installed, but when trying to run minecraft it says

```
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.7.0
```

I'm not the best with Ubuntu and I really can't figure out what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `Minecraft.link`? If you're using Wine to run Minecraft, you'll have to install Java for Wine. Or see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft

Comment: Please just paste the codes/commands/errors here not screenshot

Answer (score 0):

1. By default open-jdk is used in ubuntu, cause for your issue might be not setting up environment variable for java or still ubuntu is using
   open-jdk.
2. for that run this command in your terminal `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
3. you will get options to select which version of java to use,make
   sure you select the oracle java 7/8
4. if that doesn't work start setting up variables as follows:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit   /etc/profile
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   export JAVA_HOME 
   export JRE_HOME 
   export PATH
   ```

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install open-jdk, This command from Terminal will remove the OpenJDK and set Java as default, If that doesn't work, Update your Java 8.